# A necessary and sufficient condition for a matrix to be invertible

Tags: matrices, inverse, diagonalization

Let $B$ be a square matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $B^3 = 0$. What is the necessary and sufficient condition on $\alpha$ for the matrix $B + \alpha I_n$ to be invertible? Provide the inverse matrix in that case.

I attempted to calculate $(B + \alpha I)^m$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}$ using the binomial theorem (retaining only terms with a power of $k$ less than 3), but it did not yield any meaningful result.

Comment: If $\alpha=0,$ $B+\alpha I_n$ is not invertible (do you agree?). If $\alpha\ne0,$ you can assume wlog $\alpha=-1$ (can you see why?) and calculate $(I-B)\sum_{n=0}^\infty B^n.$

Comment: I understood! If $\alpha = 0$, since $B$ is nilpotent, it is not invertible. And if $\alpha$ is nonzero, by scaling, we can assume $\alpha = -1$, as $B^3 = 0$, the serie associated with $(B^k)$ is convergent, and by taking the product, we obtain $I_n$. Thank you @AnneBauval !